# Minecraft Slime Calculator Algorithm

Tags: java, python, minecraft

I want to create a minecraft slime calculator and I've found the algorithm [here](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Slime#Spawning). However, I don't know java very well at all, and I want to translate this over to python. To do that, I need to know what things like `0x4c1906` mean. is that just a basic pointer that I can keep the same in python? Do I have to use some sort of binary conversion or something? I'm confused as to what the pointers are and how I should handle them in my python programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x4c1906` is not a pointer, it's a hexadecimal value and means 4987142 in the decimal notation.

Comment: so can I just put that number in my python code instead of the hexadecimal value and it will work fine? Or should I somehow keep it as a hex value in case it gets truncated?

Comment: @bspymaster It shouldn't get truncated or anything since that's just the decimal notation, though.

Comment: so then why would they put it in hex notation in the first place? saves bits...?

Comment: @bspymaster I can't say. I don't know the reason for why they chose to represent it like this. It doesn't save any bits  except maybe in the string representation. But it's a format popularily used in programming.

Answer (score 1):

The several hexadecimal constants in the java code snippet,

```
Random rnd = new Random(seed + 
                    (long) (xPosition * xPosition * 0x4c1906) + 
                    (long) (xPosition * 0x5ac0db) + 
                    (long) (zPosition * zPosition) * 0x4307a7L + 
                    (long) (zPosition * 0x5f24f) ^ 0x3ad8025f);
return rnd.nextInt(10) == 0;
```

are being used to compute a seed for a random number generator (an RNG).  To replicate the effect of the java code you need to use the RNG supplied by java runtime system.  In C++ it is easy to compute the same value for the seed by C++ code quite similar to the java, and easy to initialize an RNG via srand(), but the random number sequence usually will be different in C++ than in java.  As noted in an [old daniweb post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/1769/c-random-numbers#), different C++ implementations typically use different RNG's from each other and given any seed to start will generate different number sequences.  By contrast, [java standards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) specify “particular algorithms” for the `Random` class, to make results replicable and portable.  See the link for extra bits of code you will need to implement to get the same results.

Comment: WEll do you think it would be easier to transfer it to python?

Comment: He has a good point there with the different random number generator in Java. I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code in Python, but use Java's pseudorandom number generator, look into Jython!